# In mc within tmux ctrl-o doesn't work

Tags: linux, tmux, midnight-commander

When I run mc within tmux:

```
$ tmux
$ mc
```

'Ctrl-o' in mc desn't work properly: mc panes disappear, but the shell command prompt doesn't appear, and pressing any key causes mc panes appear again. When mc is started not within tmux, Ctrl-o works normally.

How this problem can be corrected?

Comment: It works for me in Debian 8 using tmux 1.9-6, mc 3:4.8.13-3

Comment: If I remember correctly it worked for me too, but I'm on rolling release (Arch, tmux 2.01, mc 4.8.14) and some recent upgrade probably changed something to cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try run mc with -x option ?

```
mc -x

Terminal options
  -x, --xterm                    Forces xterm features
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> in mc work properly and mouse too.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> - select file(s), insert doesn't work (on my notebook)